# Is there a definitive lower limit of number of primes between $n$ and $2n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

We know from the Prime Number Theorem that total number of primes below $x$ is $x/\ln(x)$

And the number of primes between $x$ and $2x$ is $$\dfrac{2x}{\ln(2x)} - \dfrac{x}{\ln(x)}$$

Let's say if there should be $4$ primes between $x$ and $2x$, then the value of $x$ is approximately $20$.

So say $23$ to $46$ there should be no less than $4$ primes. But this is an asymptotic formula. And need not always hold true for all numbers.

So is there a definitve formula to get lower limit of number of primes between $n$ and $2n$?

Comment: suggest you work out a way to program this up to some bound. That being said, computed results on prime gaps, for example, are far more optimistic than anything that can be proved.  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maier%27s_theorem

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0907/0907.5232.pdf), i.e. one of the Ramanujan's theorems.

Comment: Just a quick off topic question, @MrGreenGold.  Are you from Wisconsin, US?  Green and Gold mean something to Wisconsites!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known that
$$
\frac{x}{{\log x - 1}} < \pi (x) < \frac{x}{{\log x - 1.1}},
$$
whenever $x\geq 60184$ (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442v1). Thus, a lower bound is
$$
\pi (2x) - \pi (x) > \frac{{2x}}{{\log (2x) - 1}} - \frac{x}{{\log x - 1.1}},
$$
whenever $x\geq 60184$.

Comment: And this being math.stackexchange it’s the natural logarithm (in cs.stackexchange it would be base 2).